# How can you prove the derivate of $e^x$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

My question is related to the prove that $\frac{dy}{dy}e^x=e^x$

I now a prove, but I think is can  be applied to any $\alpha^x$, therefore I want to know why it does not work like that.

The proof

$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^x=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x} e^h-e^x}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x (e^h-1)}{h}=e^x \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}$$

After the evaluation of the limit
$$lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1 \therefore \frac{dy}{dx}e^x=e^x$$

Comment: It depends on how you define $e$

Comment: You don't have $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\alpha^h-1}{h}=1$ for any $\alpha$.

Comment: Can you expand on why, because from my analysis it could be, of course I now it is wrong... But I cannot seem to get it right

Comment: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^h-1}h=\ln a$$

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: This really, really REALLY depends on how you define $e$, how you define, $e^x$, how you define $\ln x$ and how you define $b^x$.  It doesn't matter how you  define them but these fall from definitions.  But exactly how they fall depends on what order you define your terms.

Comment: Okay.  You biggest gap is $\lim \frac {e^h -1}h = 1$.  Why would that be true?  It is *not* true that $\lim \frac {b^h -1}h = 1$. ... Actually $\lim \frac {\alpha^h -1}h = \ln b$. But why would *that* be true.  Really depends on definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you assume that $e^{m+n} = e^me^n$? and why do you assume $\lim \frac {e^h-1}h = 1$? and why do you assume $\lim\frac {\alpha^h - 1}h = 1$?

That last assumption is incorrect.  $\lim \frac {\alpha^h -1}h = \ln \alpha$ and not $1$.

But why?

It depends on your definition.

1. Standard definitions

The standard set of definitions *IS* bass-ackward.  But it is the most analytical and consistant.  With the standard definitions we don't have *any* concept of what $b^x$ means at first or what $\log_b m$ means.

We start by defining for $x > 0$ that $\ln x := \int_{1}^x \frac 1t dt$. As $\frac 1x$ is positive we know this integral exists and the function is strictly increasing and is injective $(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$.  And as for positive $n$ we know $\int_1^n \frac 1t dt > \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{k+1}$ which is unbounded and of for $0< \frac 1n < 1$ then $\int_1^{\frac 1n} \frac 1tdt < -\sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)$ which is also unbounded, we know that $\ln x =\int_{1}^x\frac 1t dt$ is a bijection from $(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$.

And we define $Exp(x)$ as the inverse function of $\ln x$.

We define $e$ and $Exp(1)$ that is the number so that $\int_1^e \frac 1x = 1$.

We define for $b> 0$ the function $b^x = Exp(x\ln b)$.  (This means, by the way that $e^x = Exp(x\ln e) = Exp (x*1) = Exp(x)$. And that if $e^x =m$ then being an inverse function of $Exp$ that means $\ln m = \ln(Exp x) = x$ so our concept of $\ln$ but a logarithm telling what power we raise something to works.)

We have to prove that $b^{x+y} =b^xb^y$ though.  This is equivalent of proving $\ln wv = \ln w +\ln v$ or that $\int_1^w \frac 1t dt + \int_1^v \frac 1t dt = \int_1^{wv} \frac 1t dt$.  If we let $u=\frac 1vt$ then $\frac 1v du=dt$ and $\frac 1t dt=\frac 1v\frac 1uvdu =\frac 1udu$ and $\int_1^w \frac 1tdt = \int_v^{vw}\frac 1udu = \int_v^{vw}\frac 1tdt$.

So $\ln v + \ln w = \int_1^v \frac 1tdt + \int_1^w\frac 1tdt = \int_1^v \frac 1tdt + \int_v^{vw}\frac 1tdt=\int_1^{vw}\frac 1t dt = \ln vw$.

So that's it.  Then inverse function is $Exp(x)Exp(y) = Exp(x+y)$ and $b^xb^y=Exp(x\ln b)Exp(y\ln b)=Exp(x\ln b+ y\ln b)=b^{x+y}$.

(And as result if $k$ is a positive integer $b^k = b^{1+1+1....+1} = b^1b^1b^1....b^1= b*b*b*....b$.  Our very *first* meaning of what $b^x$ is *supposed* to mean has been proven consistent. ... Oh, yeah.  $b^1 = exp(\ln b)=b$... guess we hae to prove that too.)

.......

One final thing $e=\lim_{n\to \infty}  (1+ \frac 1n)^n$.  Why?

Consider $\ln e = \int_1^e\frac 1tdt = 1$.

$\int_a^b f(t)dt = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}(\frac {b-a}n\times f(a+k\frac {b-a}n)$

so $\ln e = 1$ means

$\int_{1}^e \frac 1t dt = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(\frac {e-1}n\times\frac 1{1+\frac{e-1}n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(-\frac {nk}{e-1})=1$

So if you squint the result follows.

Okay.......

Now we can START

SO $\frac {de^x}{dx} = \lim \frac {e^{x+h}-e^x}h =e^x\lim \frac {e^h-1}h$.

What is $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {e^h-1}h$?

Well it is $\lim_{n\to \infty} n( {e^{\frac 1n}-1})=\lim n((1+\frac 1n)^n)^{\frac 1n} - 1)=\lim (n(1+\frac 1n)-1)=\lim 1=1$

Furthermore $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {b^h - 1}h= \lim \frac {e^{h\ln b} -1 }h=\lim_{n\to \infty} n(e^{\frac 1n \ln b}-1) =\lim n((1+\frac 1n)^{\ln b}-1)=\ln b$.

Comment: nice answer....

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$\alpha = e^{\log \alpha}$$

Therefore

$$\frac{\alpha^x - 1}{x} = \frac{e^{x\log \alpha} - 1}{x} = \log \alpha \frac{e^{x \log \alpha} - 1}{x \log \alpha}$$

and $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\alpha^x - 1}{x} = \log \alpha$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\alpha^x$$

So $$y=e^{xln\alpha}$$

Or simply $$lny=xln\alpha$$

Differentiate both sides to get

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=yln\alpha$$

Answer (score 0):

One way is, if you define it by its power series, $e^x=\sum \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$, you can check upon differentiation termwise that the derivative is the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is why is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $e^x = e^x$ and why isn't  $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $a^x \neq a^x$. The proof is simple.

Let $y = a^x$, taking $log$ on both sides

$\Rightarrow  logy = xloga$

Now diffentiating both wrt x sides we have,

$\Rightarrow  \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = loga$

$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = y * loga$

Now y = a^x
$\Rightarrow   \frac{dy}{dx} = a^x * loga$

Now in the case of $y = e^x $ using the same approach we get $\Rightarrow   \frac{dy}{dx} = e^x * loge$ and since $loge = 1$ we get $ \frac{dy}{dx} = e^x $

I hope this solved your doubt.